# hitting time for a continuous time markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

Brad’s relationship with his girl friend Angelina changes between Amorous, Bickering, Confusion, and Depression according to the following transition rates when t is the time in months.
[image]

They are amorous now. What is the expected amount of time until depression sets in?

I am using the book by Durrett. There is a formula in the book for this type of question. However, I am not sure how to use it. We want to hitting time from state 0 to state 3.

Comment: The expected time to hit state $j$ starting at state $i$ is $u(i)$ where $(Qu)(k)=-1$ for $k \neq j$ and $u(j)=0$. This is a system of four linear equations in four unknowns, and it has a unique solution.

Comment: @Ian Can you give me an example? So I know u(3)=0. What's Q in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Q is your matrix Q.

Comment: @Ian I knew that... Can you kindly walk me through the set up for u(2)?

Comment: The system looks like $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 4 & -6 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & -6 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} u = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.